# android: proper way to wait while phone is in sleep state (using TTS)

Tags: android, timer, wait, text-to-speech

I have an app that uses TTS in continuos way. Once it started, it should keep creating questions and answers. I’d like however to wait a certain amount of time before the answer is given.

Currently I am using this

```
public void WaitSeconds(int seconds) {
    long time0, time1, diff;
        time0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    do{
        time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        diff = time1 - time0;
    }
    while (diff < seconds * 1000);
    }
```

This does work, however, only until the phone enters sleep state. After that, it keeps working if seconds is set to 3 or less, otherwise it start to wait a apparently random time. The answer might come after 10 seconds or even a minute in an unpredictable way (to me at least). 
When I press any button the app "wakes up" and utters the answer but I need to have it just going without user input.

EDIT ––––––––––––––––––––––

I’m trying to use WakeLock, as suggested, but it does not seem to work.

```
  PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "TTS Wake Lock");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
```

The error message is: "Wakelock finalized while still held" 
I’ve seen other people had this problem, but solve by moving the code to onCreate. In my case it didn’t solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run when the phone is off, you need to use a wakelock.  This allows you to keep the phone on (either keep the screen on or let it turn off but keep running).

Comment: Also, that's a horrible way of sleeping.  You're burning clock cycles doing nothing which will kill the battery.  You should use an alarm so you aren't busy waiting.

Comment: But isn’t WakeLock hard on battery as well? That’s why I thought I have to avoid it in the first place.

Comment: Yes, but not as hard as a busy loop.  You also don't need a full wake lock, just a partial (CPU only, no display).

Comment: Good. I’m trying to make it work, but I just get error "Wakelock finalized while still held" as soon as I call acquire()...